# Is there any relation between the Planck length and the infinite decimals of Pi?

Tags: units, error-analysis

Is there any relation between the Planck length and the infinite decimals of Pi?

In a book that I'm reading (A History of the Circle: Mathematical Reasoning and the Physical Universe) it suggests that if you were to plot the precision of 9 digits of Pi on the surface of a circle the size of the Earth, that you would have a rounding error the equivalent to a quarter of an inch for 25,000 miles circumference.

This led me to think about the fact that we have calculated 2.7 trillion digits of Pi, and that made me think about how large the circumference of a circle would have to be for the rounding error to be equal to or smaller than the Planck length.

Comment: Why would anyone ever need to know Pi to 2.7 trillion digits, given larger uncertainty intrinsic in the physical universe? It helps develop mathematical methods, and I think there is some mathematically interest in knowing if the digits sequence recurs, is random or even terminates - maybe ask on math.

Comment: There's no connection I know of and as the Planck Length has a dimensional value (length) and Pi has no dimensional value (it's either an angle in radians or a pure number depending on context) I don't see any way to derive one from the other, or that doing so would make sense.

Comment: It isn't math for math's sake that makes me ask. The 'object of the refinement of Pi' is to further predictions about the universe. Might there be a limit to the usefulness of the number based on the smallest measurable length in the universe?

Comment: Yeah we don't need a precision of $10^{-2.7trillion}$ the observable universe is only of the order of $10^{59}$ plank lengths across, not even close.

Comment: I'm sorry but why should there be any connection at all?

Comment: The question is just this. What's the most precise spatial distance a physicist is ever likely to need to measure? (It's not relating the constants in the sense of an equation. Only that PI is a trignometric constant and thus is used to describe space)

Comment: The planck length formula actually has a $\pi$ in it.

Comment: I think the question is interesting on a high school level, it is ontopic and clear, and yes it is useful with the explained "no" answer below. I can't really understood its vote count.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's numerology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circumference and the radius are related as follows:
$$c = 2\pi r$$

$$dc = 2r .d\pi$$

To have an error of planck length in the magnitude, you would need a circle of radius:

$$r = \frac{dc}{2 d\pi}$$

$$r = \frac{1.6 \times 10^{-35}}{2\times10^{-2.7\times 10^{12}}}$$

$$r = 0.8 \times 10^{2.7 \times 10^{12} - 35} \approx 10^{2.7 \times 10^{12}}$$

You would need a circle of radius of $10^{2.7 \times 10^{12}}$ times the diameter of the observable universe.

Comment: Thanks for the math. @JMLCarter above said as much without the math, but this clarified his answer for the math elites. Thank you all for your help.